# Write dictionary containing float values to file: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary contain float values such as the below format:

```
{'11': 0.5, '13': 1.0, '12': 0.5, -1: 3, '14': 0.0}
```

I am trying to write the dictionary into a csv file in the format of:

```
11,0.5
13,1.0
12,0.5
...
```

I am defining a function as below and it always has the error of "Float object not interable".

```
def writeDict_test(r, filename):    
    r"""
    r: dictionary object: {'1':0.9, '2':0.6,'3':0.5,...}
    filename: include path and .csv file. e.g. "C:\Users\results.csv"
    """
    with open(filename, "a") as input_file:
        for k, v in r.items():
            for t in v:                
                line = "%s,%s" % ((k,) + t)
                print(line, file=input_file)
```

The above method works well when the dictionary contains integer as values. I am using Python 3.5.
Can anyone explain to me why and show me how I can achieve this? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the variables you are passing to your `writeDict_test` function ?

Comment: The error says that you are trying to iterate over a float. I think in the second for `v` is a float (which causes the errore).

Comment: The inner `for` is not neccessary for yor data structure. Also note the difference between `'0.9'` and `.9`. One might be a string, depending on your preprocessing.

Comment: Your problem is here `for t in v:` - you are trying to iterate over a float which explains the error you are getting.

Comment: There are no floats involved here; the keys are strings, and the values are sets of strings. What does `r` *really* look like?

Comment: What is `(k,) + t` supposed to do? You are creating a `tuple` and trying to add a `string` - which obviously won't work. `line = "{}, {}\n".format(k, v); input_file.write(line)` would work. With that your code works for the example data structure, so obviously you aren't showing what `r` really looks like.

Comment: @chepner you are right. The r looks like this: {'11': 0.5, '13': 1.0, '12': 0.5, -1: 3, '14': 0.0}. Should have printed it out and posted it earlier! My apology and thanks for your inputs!

Comment: `interable`: Please do not bury your floats. They are intended to run free. They can not flourish underground, hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the inner loop, if your values contains only one element, you can use `pop()` like this:

```
my_dict = {'1':{'0.9'}, '2':{'0.6'},'3':{'0.5'}}

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(k, v.pop()))
```

If you do not want your original dictionary to be altered, you can use `list()` to convert your sets to lists like below:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(k, list(v)[0]))
```

**Edit:**

With the new input, it becomes even simple as all you need is just to write `(key, value)` pairs like this:

```
my_dict = {'11': 0.5, '13': 1.0, '12': 0.5, -1: 3, '14': 0.0}

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: This mutates values on `my_dict` though.

Comment: @niemmi You're right, If that's an issue, OP can copy the dictionary

Comment: it says: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pop'.

Comment: @ZhicongPan did you test with the same dictionary above?

Comment: Just copy and past the example I gave above and it should work for you!

Comment: @ettanany sorry, my bad. Appologize that the dictionary looks like this: {'11': 0.5, '13': 1.0, '12': 0.5, -1: 3, '14': 0.0}.

Comment: If this is the dictionary that you need to use, you should add it also to the question.

Comment: @ettanany yup! just done! thanks a lot for your inputs!

Comment: Have a preemptive +1 in anticipation of adapting to the real `dict`.

Comment: @ZhicongPan Please take a look at the edit (for your new dict)

Comment: @ettanany Thanks! it works! Yeah. Your are right. It is much simplier. I try implementing it using list and worked also. But your method of using dictionary is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

a={'1':{'0.9'}, '2':{'0.6'},'3':{'0.5'}}
b = dict(zip(a.keys(), map(lambda x: next(iter(x)), a.values())))
with open('new_file','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(b.items())
```